# Debian error message: "Unable to find LVM volume", but then boots successfully

Tags: debian, lvm, encryption, luks

I was trying to encrypt all the HDD during the installation process of Debian 8 Jessie using full disk encryption + LVM, and I did it, but, there are a little "problem".

Before the system asks me the password to unlock the disk, it display a message:

```
Loading, please wait...
[5.004102] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Volume group "lvm_group" not found
Skipping volume group lvm_group
Unable to find LVM volume lvm_group/root
Volume group "lvm_group" not found
Skipping volume group lvm_group
Unable to find LVM volume lvm_group/swap
Please unlock disk sda5_crypt:
```

But when I introduce the password and press Enter, the system boots successfully without any problem. I can't understand why.

I found some people with the similar issues in other forums and articles/manuals, but the ones I found just can't boot after the message "Unable to find LVM volume", but I can boot the system after introducing the password.

My fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/lvm_group-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4f7e12ab-84d3-4715-bab4-62cf5033ca8a /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/lvm_group-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/lvm_group-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

My crypttab:

```
sda5_crypt UUID=21feadfc-72e7-4a2c-b5f2-0c9ca3137b03 none luks
```

My /proc/cmdline:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/lvm_group-root ro quiet
```

So how can I fix it and avoid these messages? I feel like I've tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an error, so you shouldn't try to make it go away.

The scripts in your initramfs are opportunistically checking to see if they can activate the LVM VG that contains your root device before they bother asking for a passphrase to decrypt any encrypted devices. In the case that your root device is not encrypted, this will work, and the system will proceed to boot without delay. Otherwise, you get an opportunity to enter a passphrase to decrypt any possible encrypted devices, and then it tries again to access the VG. See:

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot
```

especially the function `activate_vg()` in each of those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those who come to this page via DuckDuckGo.

This is a long-standing Debian bug (albeit a cosmetic one). Check out this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=544651

If it bothers you, patch it like so:

```
--- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 2017-03-17 19:03:07.000000000 +0300
+++ /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 2019-08-17 17:40:29.371725145 +0300
@@ -20,7 +20,15 @@
 fi
.
 lvchange_activate() {
-    lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@"
+    # Workaround for making LVM less noisy.
+    # See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/iAAVTXslawQ ("Bug#799295: lvm2: Errors about lvmetad on boot")
+    if grep -sqw "quiet" /proc/cmdline; then
+        mkdir -p /run/log
+        echo "Running script '$0' on $(date)" >> /run/log/initrd-lvm.log 2>&1
+        lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@" >> /run/log/initrd-lvm.log 2>&1
+    else
+        lvm lvchange -aay -y --sysinit --ignoreskippedcluster "$@"
+    fi
 }
.
 activate() {
```

Basically, copy /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2 to /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/lvm2, patch it (e.g. using the patch above or something similar), then add the `quiet` parameter to your kernel command line.

Rebuild your initramfs.

Reboot.

Enjoy :)