# Boot process tries to mount nonexistent logical volume

Tags: debian, lvm

During boot, my system displays this message.

```
Loading, please wait...
  One or more specified logical volume(s) not found.
Unable to find LVM volume vg_ssd/swap
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
[...]
```

Then, it finishes booting.

It's trying to mount a logical volume that used to exist, before I removed it. `vg_ssd/swap` is not in `/etc/fstab` anymore, so why is it trying to mount it?

Edit: I found a file in my initial ramdisk with `/dev/mapper/vg_ssd-swap` in it. Regenerating initramfs doesn't make it go away.

```
$ mkdir bootimg; cd bootimg
$ zcat /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64 | cpio -i
$ cat conf/conf.d/resume
RESUME=/dev/mapper/vg_ssd-swap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

initrd is trying to check whether the computer is resuming from hibernate. Even though swap is not in `/etc/fstab`, it's still in the config file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Edit that file, and comment out the only line. Change

```
RESUME=/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_name
```

to

```
#RESUME=/dev/mapper/vg_name-lv_name
```

Regenerate initrd. Run:

```
update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```

See also: [Debian error message: "Unable to find LVM volume", but then boots successfully](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204371/debian-error-message-unable-to-find-lvm-volume-but-then-boots-successfully) and https://askubuntu.com/questions/292878/how-to-set-swap-in-etc-initramfs-tools-conf-d-resume-if-i-have-two-swap-partito

Answer (score 3):

You have to edit `initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and change there:

```
RESUME=/dev/mapper/vg_ssd-swap
```

To the partition you have your swap now.

Then you regenerate initramfs again; one of my preferred ways is with:

```
 dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

Comment: Ninja'd me. :) I ended up commenting that line out, because I no longer have swap.

Comment: @NickODell Oh, I did not notice the other answer was the original OP.

Comment: @NickODell  I prefer the dpkg-reconfigure than going through all the motions.